# json Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: java, android, json

I have already read many answers about the same error, but nothing helps me.

Here I try to parse Json into my data class and get an error:

```
ErrorResponse bodyResponse = App.getGson().fromJson(responseString, ErrorResponse.class);
```

The error is : BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

This is my response string:

```
'{"title":"AccessCheckException","details":{"message":"User doesn't have authorized access."}}'
```

And Data class:

```
public class ErrorResponse {
    public String title;
    public Details details;

    public ErrorResponse() {
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Details getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
    }}
```

What is wrong?

My Details class code (I reduced get/set to post it)

```
public class Details {
public String code;
public String msg;
public Attachment attachment;
public String message;
public String description;

public Details() {
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your model and Your response json doesnt match

Comment: @ABDevelopers what is the difference?

Comment: Add your Details.class

Comment: Is this simple quote at beginning in `'{"title":"` part of the response ?

Comment: @PeterMmm yes its response body

Comment: So, strip it away. Your JSON starts with a quote and not with a `{`.

Comment: `'{"title":"AccessCheckException","details":{"message":"User doesn't have authorized access."}}'` is clearly not a valid JSON (due to `'` in the beginning and ending)

Comment: clearly not a valid json because it starts with  '

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`ErrorResponse.java`  is mismatch with your json

```
    public class ErrorResponse {

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("details")
    @Expose
    private Details details;

    public String getTitle() {
    return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    }

    public Details getDetails() {
    return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Details details) {
    this.details = details;
    }

    public class Details {

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
    return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: why downvote is it wrong?

Comment: It s not my downvote, I m trying your answer, thx

Comment: It does not helped

Comment: what error are you getting?after added this code

Comment: The same error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: App.getGson().fromJson(responseString, ErrorResponse.class)  what is the value of  responseString is it your string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161813/discussion-between-r2r-and-manofwar).